# repaint() not working on JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

I have a problem, when i call `repaint()` on `JDialog`, I see nothing on the screen, but when i  move the `JDialog` by my self, I see what i wanted to paint.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class dude extends JFrame {

    private static int cnt = 0;

    public dude() {
        super("ff");
        makeFrame();
    }

    public void makeFrame() {
        new Dialog(this);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Dialog extends JDialog {

        public Dialog(JFrame frame) {
            super(frame, "ff", true);
            makeFrame();
        }

        public void makeFrame() {
            getContentPane().addMouseListener(new M(this));
            setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            pack();
            setLocation(200, 200);
            setSize(400, 400);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private class M extends MouseAdapter {

            private JDialog dialog;

            public M(JDialog dialog) {
                this.dialog = dialog;
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                P p = new P(e.getX(), e.getY());
                p.repaint();
                dialog.add(p);
            }

            private class P extends JPanel {

                private int x, y;

                public P(int x, int y) {
                    this.x = x;
                    this.y = y;
                }

                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
                }
                /*public void paint(Graphics g)
                 {
                 g.setColor(Color.black);
                 g.drawOval(x,y,10,10);
                 }*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's weirdest piece of code I've seen for a while, but.  You're immeditate problem is with you `mouseClicked` event...

Replace your `p.repaint` call with a call to the dialogs `revalidate` method.

```
P p = new P(e.getX(), e.getY());
dialog.add(p);
dialog.revalidate();
```

Your repaint method would have done nothing any way, it was being called before you panel was realized (connected to the screen)

Comment: I LOVE YOU SO MUCH MAN,thanks its working :D,but can you explain what is revalidate?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to look into the coding style you adhering to. Though, leave that for latter part, simply add this method to your M Class

```
public void setValues(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    repaint();
}
```

And make `p` an `Instance Variable` of your `Dialog` Class. And inside your `mouseClicked()` method, simply call this method. And remove the constructor part, since you initializing a new `JPanel` for each drawing which I guess is not good in any sense. When you simply can draw the new thingy on the same `JPanel`